# Read the text of a message box and store in variable using VBScript

Tags: windows, vbscript, error-handling, scripting

in one of my QTP process, i need to read the text in the message and decide whether to press OK or Cancel. Please help me to achieve the same.

I have used vbscript as below (oShell.Appactivate)

```
Dim ClosingValue
WScript.Sleep 2000 

Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
If oShell.AppActivate("Warning Message")=True Then
    While Not oShell.AppActivate ("Warning Message"):Wend
    oShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}" 
    ClosingValue = "Warning Message"
ElseIf oShell.AppActivate ("Error Message")=True Then
    While Not oShell.AppActivate ("Error Message"):Wend
    oShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}" 
    ClosingValue = "Error Message"
End If
```

Thanks in Advance
Prashanth

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible like this
when you do AppActivate, your VB script goes on halt until the other application terminates.
Also, i don't know any methods to read the content of the message (but that could be only because i don't know everything :) )

Perhaps you could describe what you need to accomplish here. i would try to pass some values by another mean, and there's plenty.
What is the Application that open this message box?

also, i don't see the need for `While Not oShell.AppActivate ("Error Message"):Wend`, since the windows is already activated by the previous line, if any windows is named this way

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I m running an automation script on a windows based application which throws a modal popup i need to read the message box and store it in a variable and then to a excel spreadsheet.

Comment: I guess you can't get this application to store values anywhere? If you run the automation script, can't you get this value from elsewhere than the popup?